# CPU overheating, Ubuntu, 92C

Tags: cpu, overheating, temperature

just moved from Windows to Ubuntu, installed some tools, porting my c++ app in a few days my laptop feeled overheated Sensors output below https://ctxt.io/2/AABQ-PCsEg

I measured temperature on Windows with app Speccy, using heavy C++ app and Warcraft3 (separately) Temperature never hit over 80 degrees.

Comment: CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE=y
trying to disable below
$ sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for ondemand